# brew install package asks to install command line tools from a path that doesn't exist

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, xcode, command-line-tool

I messed up my command line tools. I already had them installed, I also installed the beta 2 macOS 10 version from the apple developers site because the command `brew install putty` was asking me to either remove Xcode or upgrade it. (Here is where I messed up, instead of installing an upgraded version of Xcode.app, I installed Xcode command line tools 10.14)

So now the command `brew install putty` gives the error

```
Error: Your Xcode (9.4.1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 10.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
The installer is located at:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

when I run `xcode-select --install` it says the command line tools are already installed.

If I remove Xcode.app it shows that:

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the stan
dalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
The installer is located at:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the stan
dalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
The installer is located at:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

and the path mentioned in the above errors for the `pkg` file for me to install doesn't exist

Comment: did find any solutions?

Comment: @rv7284 actually yes, since the command line tools have been updated and my efforts to install a downgraded version failed because they every time got installed in a directory that had a lower precedence in the path, I had to ultimately download and install the full updated (and compatible version of) Xcode after which following the uninstallation steps it properly removed itself along with the command line utilities. So now there was already one downgraded and stable version of command line utilities left in my path which made everything work perfectly

Comment: It would be great if you can craft an answer with steps or something similar. Facing the same issue and stuck in chicken-&-egg situation.